# Initialize vector of unique_ptr with default values (nullptr?)

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

I have a templated function which takes number of elements and, possibly, initial value of parameterized type. If no initial value is supplied it assumes there is a default constructor for this type.
Within this function I declare `std::vector` of given number of elements and initial value assigned to them.

All is fine as long as template type is not `unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
void define_vector(size_t size, const T& init_val=T())
{
  vector<T> sample(100, init_val);
}

int main()
{

  define_vector<int>(100);   //<-- this works

  define_vector<unique_ptr<int> >(100); //<-- this does not
  return 0;
}
```

I understand that it tries to copy `unique_ptr` which is not allowed (deleted constructor). But is there any way around this?

I can of course to define 2 versions of function -- one with and another without initial value as a parameter. But is it the only way?

Update: To clarify apparent misunderstanding. I understand that the code does not make sense/should not compile when using not-default `unique_ptr`. What I have in mind is the following. Assume that there is a class `Foo` with only explicit constructor which takes an `int` value as a parameter. Therefore

```
define_vector<Foo>(100);    //does not make sense and does not compile
define_vector<Foo>(100, Foo(42));  //makes sense and compiles.
```

However:

```
//does not make sense and does not compile
define_vector<unique_ptr<int> > (100, std::make_unique<int>(42));
//does make sense but still does not compile
define_vector<unique_ptr<int> > (100);
```

So is it possible to make the second case above work without resorting to function overloading?

Comment: What is the expected result for a call `define_vector(100, std::make_unique<int>(42));`?

Comment: This is of course the stripped down example. In reality vector<T> is the member of class and I want to initialize it in a constructor.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Think again: What is the result that you would expect for that call? You might find that answering this tangential question will already provide you an answer to why your original code did not work.

Comment: I want vector `sample`, which in reality is defined as a member of templated class, to be initialized and filled with the default values. Function `define_vector` is, in real life, constructor of such class.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. What *exactly* do you want the vector to contain for the call that I gave? Just to be clear, I am not asking this just to annoy you. This actually relates directly to the core of your question, which you will hopefully realize yourself once you start thinking about it.

Comment: Totally agree with @ComicSansMS. I assume, that `define_vector(42, 42)` should create a `std::vector<int>` filled with `42`, when `define_vector(42, std::unique_ptr<int>(42))` should create a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` filled with unique pointers each storing the value `42`. Is it true?

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood the question. I do not expect you example to work. I know full well why my code does not work. This was not the question. The question was -- can I have a single function which can take an initial value or use a default constructor if it exists.

Comment: Of course you can. That's not the reason why your example breaks. Your example breaks because of the `vector<T> sample(100, init_val);` line that is *inside* that function. There is nothing wrong with the default argument.

Comment: I understand this. I know why my example breaks. The question is -- it is safe in principle to copy unique_ptr as long as it is 'unset', that is, created with default constructor. So is it possible to have a single function which covers both cases -- when we pass initial value or use default constructor which is safe to copy.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to create an array of `unique_ptr`, where all pointers have the same value (then they wouldn't be **unique**), except for the value `nullptr`. So, the function that accepts an arbitrary initial value is nonsensical for `unique_ptr`.

> I can of course to define 2 versions of function -- one with and another without initial value as a parameter. But is it the only way?

It's a simple way, so it is a good way. It may even be the simplest way, and I wouldn't bother considering if there is another way.

> can I have a single function which can take an initial value or use a default constructor if it exists

When you have C++17, this is possible:

```
template <class T>
void define_vector(size_t size, const T& init_val=T())
{
  vector<T> sample;
  if constexpr(is_copy_assignable<T>::value) {
      sample.resize(size, init_val);
  } else {
      assert(init_val == T());
      sample.resize(size);
  }
}
```

> The question is whether there is a nicer way?

No, I don't think so. The above is inferior to overloads, because it allows passing the initial argument, but it will be ignored silently, while the overload approach fails with an error as it should, when given the second argument for non-copyable type.

Comment: I understand this. However, consider this -- suppose that `T` is a class `Foo` without a default constructor. Then calling `define_vector` without the second parameter would not make sense either and it would not compile. So, here we have the opposite situation -- passing the 'defined' `unique_ptr` does not make sense and it does not compile and this is Ok. But the there is nothing wrong with copying 'default' empty `unique_ptr`, so it is possible to achieve? As to the second part -- this would assume the code duplication. The question is whether there is a nicer way?

Comment: @one_two_three yes, there is wrong with copying a `unique_ptr` even if it is empty. It is not allowed because `unique_ptr` is not copyable.

Comment: And my answer is that *no*, there is no nicer way (as far as I know) than overloads, which are a very nice way.

Answer (score 1):

With variadic template, you may do:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
void define_vector(size_t size, const Ts&... init_val)
{
    std::vector<T> sample(100, init_val...);
    // ...
}
```

Note: You may add some SFINAE to constraint `init_val` to have at most one arg if required.

Then

```
define_vector<int>(5);     // Call vector<int>(5) instead of your vector<int>(5, 0)
define_vector<int>(5, 42); // Call vector<int>(5, 42);

define_vector<unique_ptr<int> >(5); // Call vector<unique_ptr<int>>(5)
```